What does "0010 ^0.16 ___u8_ iv;" in Hex-Rays IDA Pro mean?
I want to get the parameter's value when function called, when I open the program with IDA and hover on the function name I got the message like this: 1: 0008 rsi      libsm::sm4::cipher_mode::Sm4CipherMode *self;, I know this means when the function called, I can find the self parameter's value in register $rsi, but on some functions, the message is like this:
enter image description here
How can I understand ^0.16? Is that means this parameter is not stores in any register?

You are right, it means this parameter is not stored in any register. It is stored on stack instead. First part (0) is an offset into arguments area of the stack, second part (16) is the argument's size.
EDIT: the very first part of this (0010) is the hexadecimal argument size, while the second part (rsi or ^0.16) is the so-called argument location. I don't know if it is actually documented anywhere as a thing but this doc: https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1492.shtml - describes scattered arguments including this syntax in more details.

Thanks for your reply! Now I use gdb debugging this program, How can I check the arguments in the stack?
`(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000555555a64f20 in libsm::decrypt ()
#1  0x0000555555626b6c in ?? ()
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fffffffda80:
rip = 0x555555a64f20 in libsm:::decrypt; saved rip 0x555555626b6c
called by frame at 0x7fffffffdb60
Arglist at 0x7fffffffda70, args:
Locals at 0x7fffffffda70, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffda80
Saved registers:
rip at 0x7fffffffda78
(gdb) Thestackmeans0x0000555555a64f20or0x7fffffffda70`? Sorry I'm new for this ..

0x0000555555a64f20 is a current RIP. If it is exactly at the start of this function then arguments would start at RSP + 8. I think this initial RSP is 0x7fffffffda78 so the arguments would be immediately above it starting at 0x7fffffffda80

the second part is 0.16 though, not 16. What does the "0." prefix signify? And where is that documented? because this answer definitely needs a link to some docs.

@AndreyTurkin Thanks very much! This solved my problem.
